# Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>' when user is in an AAD Group

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

Currently, I am a user who is added in Azure Active Directory. I tried login using visualstudio credentials in .Net C# but getting an error.
Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'
I can login to database using SSMS with Azure MFA.

c# code.

```
 public async Task<SqlConnection> GetAzureSqlAccessTokenAsync(
        AzureSqlConnectionOptions azureSqlConnectionOptions,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        
        var connectionStringBuilder = GetConnectionString(azureSqlConnectionOptions);
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(_azureSqlScopes);

        var chainedTokenCredential = new ChainedTokenCredential(
                                        //new ManagedIdentityCredential(),
                                        new VisualStudioCredential(),
                                        new VisualStudioCodeCredential(),
                                        new AzureCliCredential()
                                        );

        var token = await chainedTokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, cancellationToken);
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = token;
        
        try
        {
            // sanity test
            await sqlConnection.OpenAsync(); // fails here
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT GETDATE()", sqlConnection);
            var currentTime = await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            var ex = e.InnerException;
        }
        return sqlConnection;
    }
```

Comment: What is `_azureSqlScopes` ? is it `new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }` ?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 0):

With the below **c#** code, I am able to login to Azure Active Directory Authentication.

**ConnectionString:**

```cs
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "QuotesDatabase": "Server=tcp:servename.database.windows.net,1433; Database=databasename;" }
```

**Code:**

```cs
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("QuotesDatabase");
            services.AddTransient(a =>
            {
                var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var token = credential
                        .GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                            new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
                sqlConnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
                return sqlConnection;
            });
                services.AddControllers();
        }   
}
```

I set azure service authentication to retrieve the token credentials.
[image]

**Output:**
[image]